# Explain arm64 instruction STP

Tags: arm64

I am reading a source code and find the instructions below but I don't understand what it does.
Could someone please help me to understand it?

`stp    x19, x20, [x8], #16`

If only `stp    x19, x20, [x8]` I can understand.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's called the "post-index" variant, and it modifies the address after storing.
The following two are equivalent:

```
stp x19, x20, [x8], #16
```

```
stp x19, x20, [x8]
add x8, x8, #16
```

There is also a pre-index variant that modified the address *before* storing.
Again, these two are equivalent:

```
stp x19, x20, [x8, #16]!
```

```
add x8, x8, #16
stp x19, x20, [x8]
```

In my experience, this is most commonly used for pushing and popping stack frames like so:

```
some_func:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    // ...
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    ret
```

Most forms of single-register `ldr` and `str` also have these variants, for more information see section C1.3.3 ("Load/Store addressing modes") in the [ARMv8 Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest).

Comment: I think maybe you want a `!` on the `stp` in your last example?  (I really don't know why they had to make that syntax so obnoxious.)

Comment: @NateEldredge good catch, I do. Gets me time and time again, sigh.